# How come BLE ScanCallBack is being retained and not being GC'd?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm not sure if it's my code, but I just noticed in the heap dump I record with Android Studio profiler that when I start setting my variables to null to free up the reference to an object. The object itself is still allocated, and when I check the Android profiler I see that it is due to my ScanCallback. This means every time I do the following logic:

```
var sensorScanner = SensorScanner(bleAdapter)
sensorScanner = null
```

my number of allocations keep increasing by 1, but it should not be doing that. If I call that line 24 times, I see 24 allocations.

If I were to comment out the following code in my SensorScanner():

```
bleAdapter.bluetoothLeScanner.startScan(scanFilters, scanSettings, scanCallback)
```

the number of allocations will stay at 1 which is what I expect. So if I did 24 allocations experiment again, the allocation stays at 1 when I view the heap dump.

It's weird because I also don't see any exposed methods from the bleAdapter that would allow me to clear the callback.

Thank you for viewing my question, if anyone has some thoughts or tips please share them if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the method you must use to stop the scan:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeScanner#stopScan(android.bluetooth.le.ScanCallback)

Pass the same callback object you used when you started the scan.